# How to calculate Pixels/per inch of an image in different DPI?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image

How to calculate pixels/inch of an Image in different DPI ?
For example:
I have one image having height = 2048px; width= 3072px. So I want to calculate pixels per inch in 300 DPI?

Can any one help me please.

Comment: If you have 300 DPI/PPI it really is 300 pixels per inch... 1 DPI = 1 pixel per inch.

Answer (score 2):

DPI is irrelevant on the web. One pixel of image data displays as one pixel on the screen regardless the DPI setting.
Read more on the concept here
http://www.apptools.com/examples/dpi.php
http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/whatisdpi.html

Then 300 DPI basically means 300 printing dots per inch, meaning that a picture of your proportions will be 6.83 x 10.24 inches when printed.

Pixels/Print size calculator: http://auctionrepair.com/pixels.html

PS: there is a wide-spread confusion of two terms DPI and PPI. PPI is used on digital screens, DPI is used in printing.

---

### Update

Calculating *pixel/inch (PPI)* or *dots/inch (DPI)* and corresponding image size is very simple.

### Formula

```
real_width  [in] = image_width [px] / PPI [px/in]
real_height [in] = image_width [px] / PPI [px/in]
```

If you want to calculate *pixel/inch (PPI)*, just reverse the order

```
PPI [px/in] = image_width [px] / real_width [in]
```

To calculate a resolution of a real scanned image

```
image_width [px] = real_width [in] * PPI [px/in]
```

#### Examples

Image `width = 3072px`, `height = 2048px`

#### 72PPI

```
width  = 3072 / 72 = 42.67 inches
height = 2048 / 72 = 28.44 inches
```

#### 300PPI

```
width  = 3072 / 300 = 10.24 inches
height = 2048 / 300 = 6.83 inches
```

Comment: So there is no way to calculate the dpi of an image, means if I want to validate the image width a defined pixel size. can you help me on this?. I really need help on it .

Comment: I am not sure what you really want. Do you want to tell the size of an image on a screen? It depends on screen's DPI (correctly PPI). If you want the size of a printed image, then use the linked calculator - otherwise a 500px image simply is 500px no matter what DPI/PPI setting it has.

Comment: Ok then here I am telling you my requirement. when I am uploading an image to the server I need to validate the image .So here is my validation rule:  the minimum resolution of the image should be greater than 120 pixel/ inch . If minimum resolution does not match it will not upload to the server and show an error message. So now can you tell me?

Comment: @biswajit-rout Allright then what you really need is the actual _width_ and _height_ of the image, not its _pixel/inch_ ratio. If you require an image at least 160x120, then you need `width >= 160 && height >= 120`. Forget about pixel density, it's not what you want. Have you visited the first link provided? There is no difference between 72, 120 or 300 PPI in digital media.

Comment: really very much thankful to you. I leaned some new thing from you. Here is the answer of your query: yes I have gone through the links and I also agree that Its not possible to calculate pixel/inch of an image. So I just want to know that Is there any way to find out pixel /inch value. or if can it be possible to use html5 canvas for calculating this. Because my concern is to calculate only Pixels/inch in different DPI using java script. Otherwise I will take help of server side language.